# Laravel API Authentication - Passport Token

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API using Laravel. For authentication and security I am using Passport: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

I followed all the steps in the documentation. I am working with several profiles that pass through authentication, and I came across a problem, the token used by a middleware can be applied in other middleware.

In my config / auth.php file it looks like this:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'producer' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'producers',
    ],

    'coordinator' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'coordinators',
    ],
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'producers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Producer::class,
     ],

     'coordinators' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Coordinator::class,
     ],
],
```

The Coordinator model looks like this:

```
class Coordinator extends Authenticatable{

use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

protected $table = 'coordinators';
protected $guard = 'coordinator';

protected $fillable = [
    'coordinator_name', 'email', 'password', 'cpf_cnpj', 'phone'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

public function events(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')->using('App\EventCoordinator');
}}
```

And the Model Producer looks like this:

```
class Producer extends Authenticatable{
use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

protected $guard = 'producer';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'cpf_cnpj', 'phone', 'street', 'neighborhood', 'city', 'state', 'number', 'zipcode', 'complement'
];

protected $table = 'producers';

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

public function events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}}
```

On the routes I'm using the middleware set in auth.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:producer')->group(function() {
    Route::get('events', 'ProducerController@events');
});

Route::middleware('auth:coordinator')->group(function() {
    Route::get('events', 'CoordinatorController@events');
});
```

And finally the events method in the CoordinatorController looks like this:

```
public function events(){
    try{
        if(Auth::guard('coordinator')->check()){
            $events = Auth::user()->events;

            return response()->json(['events' => $events], 200);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => ['message' => 'Usuário não autenticado.']], 421);
        }         
    }catch(\Exception $err){
        return response()->json(['error' => ['code' => $err->getCode(), 'message' => $err->getMessage()]], 400);
    }
}
```

and in ProducerController:

```
public function events(){
    try{
        try{
        if(Auth::guard('producer')->check()){
            $events = Auth::user()->events;

            return response()->json(['events' => $events], 200);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => ['message' => 'Usuário não autenticado.']], 421);
        } 
    }catch(\Exception $err){
        return response()->json(['error' => ['code' => $err->getCode(), 'message' => $err->getMessage()]], 400);
    }
}
```

I am using Postman for testing, and when I use the Producer token to access the Coordinator method it works even though using different middleware in the route. Can anyone help? Something is missing?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, passport didn't support [MultiAuth](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161)

you can use widely available 3rd party multiauth support for laravel, like this [package](https://github.com/sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth).